# Laravel route works perfectly locally but not on remote. (Dingo Api)

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing, dingo-api

I am using dingo/api for a project and all of my routes work other than 1.

routes.php

```
    $api = app('api.router');
    $api->version('v1',['prefix' => 'api'], function ($api) {

        $api->post('users', "App\Http\Controllers\Auth\UsersController@store");
...
        });
```

store method :

```
/**
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Requests\Auth\StoreUserRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(StoreUserRequest $request)
    {
        if( ! $this->isAdminRequest() )
        {
            return $this->dispatch(new RegisterUserCommand($request));
        }
    }
```

This route throws `405 Method Not Allowed Exception`.

`php artisan api:routes` shows that it is registered, both locally and on server.
I am using POSTMAN to test my api and have all required fields.
In response I do get **Allow : POST**.

**NOTE :**

- There are other post routes that work perfectly.
- There are other
  UsersController routes that work perfectly
- I have tried removing all other routes and with just this, it still does not work.

**Any help is appreciated. Thanks.**

**UPDATE :**

Okay, it was a really silly mistake on my part. I was hitting **'domain/api/users/'**. Removing the trailing **'/'** worked. 
But the thing is, locally **'/'** works and not on server. 
So keeping this question on for some explanantion maybe.

Comment: Is controller class name/controller file name, same as that mentioned in route file...??

Comment: Yes, it is. As I said, there are other Users routes that work perfectly.

Comment: i was calling it without https://

Comment: Any chance of an update 4 years later? I'm running into this exact problem right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very good question and have since ran into this myself. Your update should be in an answer so if you do that, I may remove mine. The problem for me was a trailing slash in my `action` e.g. `/some/action/` instead of `/some/action` where the route expected it in the latter form.

I had assumed that Laravel would handle this optional trailing slash as a feature considering the behaviour in a local environment but this was not the case.

Comment: I've kept this because I was not able to find why this was happening. I have different configurations locally and on server. Maybe it's due to that. Or maybe it's because of any APACHE configuration or .htaccess.
I was hoping to find what can effect and cause this behaviour.

Comment: It makes sense because your local may be running nginx and your server on Apache. The way they handle things is likely the cause of the problem

Comment: No it's both Apache but different versions. I'll look into this further later and update here.

Comment: In my case it was a homestead environment which may be running nginx if not mistaken